Oscillating inverted hemisphere Lagrangian mechanics problem
I am trying to solve a hw problem on Lagrangian mechanics. Here is the problem:

The main issue I am having is setting up the kinetic energy. I don't understand whether the hemisphere has both translational and rotational energy or just one of the two. And if it has rotational energy, do we consider it from the moment of inertia of the pivot or from the center of mass?

Voting to reopen. Questioner is asking for help with a specific conceptual difficulty; this is not a "do my homework for me" question.

Probably simplest to take the moment of inertia about the hemisphere's centre of mass. Then if the centre of mass moves the hemisphere has translational kinetic energy and if the hemisphere rotates about its centre of mass then it has rotational kinetic energy. It may, of course, have both.
We are not told whether the surface on which the hemisphere rests is smooth or rough. This is crucial in determining the hemisphere's motion. If the surface is smooth there is no horizontal force on the hemisphere so its COM cannot oscillate horizontally - it can only oscillate vertically. If the surface is rough then friction acts horizontally on the hemisphere and its COM can oscillate horizontally as well as vertically.

In any circumstance, we can account for the kinetic energy of a rotating object in one of two ways:

$T = \frac12 I \omega^2$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia about the (instantaneous) pivot point and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

$T = \frac12 I_\text{cm} \omega^2 + \frac12 M v_\text{cm}^2$, where $I_\text{cm}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of mass, $M$ is the object's total mass, and $v_\text{cm}$ is the speed of the center of mass.


Both formulas will, if applied correctly, give the same answer.
However, in the present case, the second one is probably easier to use.  This is because the hemisphere's instantaneous pivot point will change as it oscillates;  and the moment of inertia of the hemisphere will be different for different "pivot points" on its curved surface.  (It's plausible that this wouldn't matter for "small oscillations" — I haven't gone through the math carefully — but my instinct would be to simply avoid this complication altogether and use the second formula to find the kinetic energy.)

Why is it that the center of mass is the special point about which we can "decompose" the energies into translational and rotational?

@mathlover123: I'm not sure that there's a better answer than "The math works out that way". The proof proceeds by writing out the velocity of each particle as the sum of the CM velocity plus its velocity relative to the CM. The KE then decomposes naturally into three terms: the usual translational KE, the rotational KE, and a "cross term" that vanishes because the net velocity of the system relative to its own CM is by definition zero.

By considering a rolling full sphere (or a wheel for simplicty), its clear, that the full sphere center moves horizontally like an the axis of a wheel during oscillating by rolling without slip.
The center moves linearly with the angle parallel to the point of contact to the rail .
In spherical coordinates wrt to the center $r,\theta, \phi$, the area of the sphere is homogenous in $$z dz =\cos \theta \ d\theta,$$ so the center of gravity is at $r/2$ with a total mass of $\rho \ 2 \pi\  r^2$
So, by elementary geometry the center of the half sphere moves on a circle of radius $r/2$ whose center oscillates linearly with the angle.
Express the cartesian position vector and the hight in terms of the rotation angle and calculate kinetic energy and potential.
Tip: points on a wheel move on cycloides.
